# Securly persist data between GET Action, View, and subsequent POST Action in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to securly store and retrieve a specific value between a GET Action, the View that gets served, and the POST Action from a form on the View.

This value is an ID of an article that the user will edit the title for. If I just use a plain hidden input in the View to pass along the data, I know that the user could change the hidden value and that could result in security problems.

Many posts I have read simply say: *"Well then just validate that the author has authorization to edit the article of the ID you get in the POST action."*

But what if this user has the authorization to edit two articles and he changes the ID to the other article he has the authorization to edit? I really don't want that.

So far, I have found two ways to solve this problem:

### **1. TempData**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    TempData["id"] = id;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var id_from_get_action = TempData["id"];
    return View();
}
```

### 2. Encrypted Token

There is a [post](http://sergeyakopov.com/tamper-proof-hidden-fields-in-asp-net-mvc/) I found where a token is generated for a hidden field and then validated on the POST action.

```
<input id="SomeProperty" name="SomeProperty" type="hidden" value="I love lamp">  
<input name="__SomePropertyToken" type="hidden" value="zqb7MIL2Y5F3jL96ncdSZOmetL8g8RAWZP8Y/w/jUAKJ89GcUViRWOZ/XtQhtICMFZb4sQtZLOpqK/WyC0TFP0B6r+3nObFGDjb0U459yzQbadC4+DLIsTmhyYeT+ZT+bnW1AEP2fgVyXXSduYIf5vns7g9nhRWTgJo8xF6NQyT6kNgyl5puq+BYc8dfhMXn">
```

---

So, back to my question. Is there a standard solution to my problem? Or are the two methods I listed the ways things are usually done?

Comment: Why do you care if the user picks the ID of the article he wants to edit by using your web page or by hand-constructing the request URL. I don't see why that could ever affect security, as long as you authorize the *request* server-side. If you could explain how that is a real-life problem, you might get better answers.

Comment: Is a user really going to be maliciously trying to hack their own data? They could just open both items, cut and paste the other properties to swap them and achieve the same result

Comment: @EricJ. The article is supposedly "archived" which means that no more editing should take place, even though it is still "owned" by an author.
So, I guess what you're saying is I should add checks not only for authorization, but also whether an article is classified as "archived"?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. You should never trust that information to the client side, since you have no control over the client. Even if the information is encrypted, it's still there and can potentially be compromised.

Comment: Can you do a check beforehand (after the request - like in the stored proc or similar) to see if the field is readonly?